# Filtering prometheus query results using binary operators

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am building a framework to show the metrics of different targets which are stored in prometheus. I have a generic api which accepts the target (instance) data and filters the data for the specified target. I have three metrics to be fetched.

```
1. 100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100) -- cpu usage
2. ((node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"} * 100) /node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"}) -- disk usage
3. 100 * avg by (instance) ((node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemFree_bytes) / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes) -- memory usage
```

I am making an API call to prometheus and getting all the data for the above queries. Now i have to filter out the result for a specific instance. So i added and ({instance:"xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9100"}) to filter out the data.

My API query looks like,

```
(100 - (avg by (instance) (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}[5m])) * 100) or ((node_filesystem_avail_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"} * 100) /node_filesystem_size_bytes{mountpoint="/",fstype!="rootfs"}) or 100 * avg by (instance) ((node_memory_MemTotal_bytes - node_memory_MemFree_bytes) / node_memory_MemTotal_bytes)) and ({instance:"xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9100"})
```

But this is not working for the queries where aggregations are used and getting no data for those. Is there any way, where i can filter out the query results based on specific labels for different queries.

Comment: If you really need to fetch the values by instance, can't you simply integrate it in the expression directly `(avg (irate(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle",instance="xx.xx.xxx.xxx:9100"}[5m])) * 100)` ?

Comment: @MichaelDoubez, I am having a framework where i will show all my targets in a table and i will get the queries for metrics separately. When i click on my target in the table, i have to filter its values out. So i need to have my filter added to the query at the end. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Grafana should do it for you.

Comment: I want to display these details in my application and i cannot use iframes to embed grafana panels into my web application. I am trying to directly query prometheus, get the data and draw charts using my charting framework.